# How to handle THREE.Mesh objects in a worker

Tags: javascript, multithreading, three.js, mesh, web-worker

I created some buildings in **three.js**. It works so far.

Based on disadvantages because of single-threaded I look for alternatives to handle large amounts of data.
Therefore I created a web-worker to build my geometry inside and send it back to main thread.

But it doesn´t work I get following error message:

> error: *buildingTileProcessor.js:332 Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': An object could not be cloned.*

After some researche I guess this kind of Object (`THREE.Mesh`) is to complex for the data clone algorithm.

Does anybody recognize the problem?
How to send back my Mesh objects?

How does it look like with **Parallel.js**. This library also uses web worker technology.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send such objects from a `WebWorker` scope/thread back to your main scope/thread. You can find more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage):

> ***aMessage***
>
> The object to deliver to the worker; this will be in the data field in the event delivered to the [DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.onmessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope/onmessage) handler. This may be any value or JavaScript object handled by the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm), which includes cyclical references.
>
> ***transferList*** `Optional`
>
> An optional [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of [Transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) objects to transfer ownership of. If the ownership of an object is transferred, it becomes unusable (neutered) in the context it was sent from and becomes available only to the worker it was sent to.
>
> Only [MessagePort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessagePort) and [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBuffer) objects can be transferred. null is not an acceptable value for the transferList.

[Here you can read about the structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm):

And there in the **Things that don't work with structured clones** you find the reason for your error.

I tried to do something similar and resigned from using webworkers. If you find some work around I would be happy to hear about it.

---

**Note:** You could create a `THREE.BufferGeometry` and then send the buffer attributes as [transferable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) back to the main thread. That is something that is technically possible, but it will be a lot of custom code to get it working.

### UPDATE

*As a response to your comment here an update:*

If you convert a `THREE.Geometry` to a `THREE.BufferGeometry` using [the `fromGeometry` method](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry.fromGeometry) you cannot send the buffer geometry directly as a transferable, but you should be able to send [the buffer arrays from the buffer attributes (`THREE.BufferAttribute`) of the buffer geometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry.attributes) as transferables and then you can rebuild the buffer attributes and the buffer geometry in the main thread using the buffer arrays you received from your worker in the message.

I haven't tested this but it should be technically possible. How much performance increase you will be able to get like this I don't know, but it sounds like worth an experiment.

```
var bufferGeometry = THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );    

// Now you can access the buffer attributes that hold buffer arrays.
// You can collect them using their name ( color, normal, position, etc )
var attribute = bufferGeometry.getAttribute( name );
var bufferArray = attribute.array;

// The index attribute is accessible like this:
var indexAttribute = bufferGeometry.getIndex();
var indexArray = indexAttribute.array;
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. Regarding to your note I have a THREE.Mesh which is a javascript object structure with vertices and so on. And I read that I can do a conversion like: `var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry);` As result I get a BufferGeometry which stores the gl data via Float32Arrays. Is this BufferGeometry a kind of arraybuffer? Because arraybuffers are transferable objects...and so it should work to send it back

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your effort.  I will try it and I will give some feedbacks back... If somebody have another way how to solve this I would be happy to hear it....